# Hash a file in Windows Store App c#

Tags: c#, hash, windows-store-apps, md5

Is there any way to Hash a hole file in c# (metro)?
Nice would be MD5.

I searched a lot, but i found nothing, can anybody help me?

All these Code samples, which i found do not work in Windows Store App!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 8(Metro) hashing algorithm are under Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core. Check this link, it contains simple example of how to hash string in C#/Metro. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmnames.md5

Comment: is it possible to hash a hole file, because it can be a picture, or something like that

Comment: Hashes operate on byte sequences.  Just feed it all your data, either all at once or in a loop.